# Decrease noise in Disparity map

Tags: emgucv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I calculated Disparity map in c# (Emgu). The attached file[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLeMK.png) is left and right image, and disparity map. The noise of disparity map is high. How can i decrease noise in disparity map?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want better result in disparity map you should have good camera calibration. The more accurate camera calibration lead to more accurate disparity map.

Comment: Dear Tiziran, Thank you for kind reply. you are right. for accurate camera calibration what parameters are most important?

Answer (score 0):

As [tiziran pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149195/decrease-noise-in-disparity-map/41233028#41233028), good (stereo) calibration is important. Since you usually calibrate each camera retrieving its whole projection matrix, it's difficult to say which of its parameters is the most important.

Stereo calibration involves also the determination of the rotation and traslation of the second camera with respect to the first camera.

In your case, some other things have to be considered:

A) in general noise depends on window correlation size and on the correlation method. Several method exists. The bigger the correlation size, the lower the noise but also the lower the precision.

B) To have disparity, points have to be seen from both your cameras. Half of each image is out the field of view of the other camera, so it would be useless (and tipically noise occurs in areas where disparity couldn't be computated). I think in this case there is too much distance / rotation between the cameras (it does not helps).

C) It is hard to have good disparity where there is no texture at all, or where the texture dimension is too bigger than the correlation window size. In your images there are zones with uniform white color and no texture

D) I think that is hard to have good disparity where the carpet is out of focus. It is my personal consideration but this fact does not help you for sure.

Comment: Dear marcoresk, Thank you for your good reply. The baseline of my stereo camera is 25 cm. Does it affect in rectifying and matching?

Comment: @ahyan in theory I'd say no, it doesn't: in theory every baseline can be used. But in order to perform the match, you must have points that can be matched: points that have to be seen from both camera (see B in my answer). Also consider this: the bigger the baseline, the bigger the "blind" area betwenn the cameras (from my experience)

Comment: you are right. I have tested on objects in more distances (in calibration and rectification), but it's not useful. I'm using Opencv website codes. is this enough? or should I change that?

Comment: @ahyan I cannot really answer to this. Please consider to accept my actual answer, or post another, more specific, question about your code. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)